# Change TabbarView in Flutter When pressed button from another class and also need to make swipe-able

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-animation

Hey I m new in flutter now m stuck with the tab bar I have four files (Class), the first one is the parent file and the other three files(Class) are the child.

Now I want to change tabbarview when I clicked the button from the child class.

I also shared my sample code please help me.

**This is My Parent Class**

```
class AddItemTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddItemTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AddItemTabState createState() => _AddItemTabState();
}

class _AddItemTabState extends State<AddItemTab> {

  final List<Widget> _fragments = [
    const ProductPurchase(),
    const ProtectionProduct(),
    const RoomProduct()
  ];
  int _page = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: MyColor.backgroundColor,
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 50.0, right: 20.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 20.0),
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: IconButton(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          constraints: BoxConstraints(),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          },
                          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("Back"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  const Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        'Add an item',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 34,
                          fontFamily: 'Inter',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                        ),
                      )),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 55,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: const TabBar(
                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                        color: MyColor.buttonColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(5),
                        ),
                      ),

                      indicatorWeight: 5,
                      indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top:50),
                      // controller: _tabController,
                      labelColor: Colors.black,
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          child: Text(
                            "Purchase",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Protection',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Room',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Expanded(
                      child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      _fragments[0],
                      _fragments[1],
                      _fragments[2],
                    ],
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

**This is My Child Class**

```
class ProductPurchase extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductPurchase({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductPurchaseState createState() => _ProductPurchaseState();
}

class _ProductPurchaseState extends State<ProductPurchase> {
  final List<Widget> _fragments = [
    const ProtectionProduct(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: MyColor.backgroundColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  elevation: 5,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  // Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  //     builder: (context) => ProductView()));
                  // _fragments[0];
                },
                child: Ink(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: MyColor.buttonColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 250,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 88.0),
                    child: const Text('Go To Next Tabbar View',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,`enter code here`
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `TabController` for this , while you already have tab Bar and tab Bar view, you can do it like

```dart
class _AddItemTabState extends State<AddItemTab>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final List<Widget> _fragments = [
  .....
  ];

  late final TabController controller = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 

........

child: TabBar(
  controller: controller,

......
Expanded(
      child: TabBarView(
    controller: controller,
```

And to move n index, here 2

```dart
onPressed: () {
  controller.animateTo(2);
},
```

To call from different widget using callback method

```dart
class ProductPurchase extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback callback;
  const ProductPurchase({Key? key, required this.callback}) : super(key: key);

.....
onPressed:  (){
  widget.callback();
},
```

Once you used this widget, provide

```dart
ProductPurchase(callback: (){
  controller.animateTo(2);
},);
```

```dart
class ProductPurchase extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback callback;
  const ProductPurchase({Key? key, required this.callback}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductPurchaseState createState() => _ProductPurchaseState();
}

class _ProductPurchaseState extends State<ProductPurchase> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      // backgroundColor: MyColor.backgroundColor,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  elevation: 5,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  widget.callback(); //this
                },
                child: Ink(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: MyColor.buttonColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 250,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 88.0),
                    child: const Text('Go To Next Tabbar View',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And fragments

```dart
  late final List<Widget> _fragments = [
    ProductPurchase(
      callback: () {
        controller.animateTo(3);
      },
    ),
    Container(color: Colors.cyanAccent, child: Stack(children: [Text("fsA")])),
    Text("2A")
  ];
```

More about [TabBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabBar-class.html)

Comment: How to call in another file controller.animateTo(2); ?

Comment: It would be better to use callback method, I think

Comment: Can you give me example using another file for better understanding

Comment: Included the last part

Comment: Are you able to complete 1st portion, with `TabController`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247440/discussion-between-mohammed-faizan-and-yeasin-sheikh).